# Reading an XML and parse through xml to get a particular value

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<department>
  <store departmentid="62" user="abc" password="abc123" store_name="abc"/>
  <store departmentid="63" user="bcd" password="bcd123" store_name="bcd"/>
  <store departmentid="65" user="xyz" password="xyz123" store_name="xyz"/>
</department>
```

I have above XML.Now in my code i have the departmentid.I want to loop through the xml and select the storename against the department id.Please Help.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var storeName = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                    .Where(s => (int)s.Attribute("departmenid") == id)
                    .Select(s => (string)s.Attribute("store_name"))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey..It is working fine... :)

Comment: @user2936112 next time please show code which you have tried to complete your task. Even if code is not great, users will tell you what is wrong and help to get solutions. Questions without code usually closed before you get any answers